# Android- Urban airship push notification not working

Tags: android, push-notification, apk

I am implemented Urban airship C2dm push notification to our application but got the following problem mentioned below.

When I deploy to the phone from eclipse, it works, and push notification received in proper manner. But,
Whenever I generate an .apk and deploy it to a phone, Push notifications are not working.

What is the deal? Not know what errors occur. Please help.

Comment: what kind of error are u getting when u r runing directly in device?

Comment: @AamirPathan Thanks for your quick response.
There is no any error in both cases. I have check all the logcat in both cases. Notifications work well when its attached with eclipse, whenever I generate the .apk file and deploy to device no any notification received. I am suffer with this problem since last week. No got any solution, even any hint what to do.

Comment: Amit I would suggest that u dump Urban Airship in favour of Google Cloud Messaging, especially since now its free

Comment: look at this issue 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232853/c2dm-to-google-cloud-messaging-gcm

this might help you,,,

Comment: @the100rabh thanks for response. Its mandatory for me to implement Urban airship push notification. Even I know well about Google Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Friends, Please guide me I have try all things which I can. I will appreciate your valuable feedback.